# X-Robots-Tag across Multiple URL

Tags: apache, http-headers

I need to add `X-Robots-Tag` in my Apache config where it can be applied to multiple URLs which are read from a file and apply the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header, is this possible? Any pointers on how to accomplish it?

My example below shows different file types, however is it possible to read the file path from a file and apply the http header?

```
<Files ~ "\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$">
 Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</Files>
```

Comment: Is the use case that you have a long list of specific URLs that you want to have the `X-Robots-Tag`?  Are they in a text file each on their own line?   Can you give an example?  Would `/category/some-page.html` be an example?

Comment: Yes Exactly, I would be something like a simple text file that would have a list of all the URL's that  need to have the `X-Robots-Tag` applied through HTTP headers when request comes through from those URL's

Comment: Does it have to be done in .htaccess?   What CMS are you using?  It might be easier to modify your content management system to add the headers

Comment: we have adobe AEM, we would need this like a self servicing file that users can change for the URL's that do not need to be indexed.